# What c# model will serialize to a JSON object with dynamic property names each having a list of lists of values?

Tags: c#, json, data-structures

What data structure/collection in C# that when I serialize using Newtonsoft.Json would give me a result like this, where the property names `"data_point1"` are dynamic and defined at runtime?

```
{
"data": {
    "data_point1": [
      [
        string,
        string
      ],
      [
        string,
        string
      ]
    ],
    "data_point2": [
        [
          string,
          string
        ],
        [
          string,
          string
        ]
      ],
   }
}
```

I tried with List of Dictionaries and it gave result like below:

```
{
    [
        {
            "data_point1": [
                [
                    string,
                    string
                ]
            ],
            "data_point2": [
                [
                    string,
                    string
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit1: changed "Property" to "data_point" as it was confusing. Dataset "data" has thousands of data points, each data point is a collection of data at a specific time.

Edit2: for anyone who this this not real Json, this is from an instruction of a 3rd party API I have to push data to

```
{ 
    "userToken": "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX", 
    "sessionToken": "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX", 
    "tvqs": 
        { 
          "tag1": [ [ "2018-01-09T12:00:00.0000000-05:00", "value" ] ], 
          "tag2": [ 
                    [ "2018-01-09T11:59:55.0000000-05:00", "value" ] , 
                    [ "2018-01-09T12:00:00.0000000-05:00", "value" ] 
                  ]  
        }
}
```

Comment: You have to post the real json,  and what you have tried so far.

Comment: It is hard to believe that VS generated either when you “paste as classes”…

Comment: That's the real Json from an API documentation, I added a comment below. I made an example version of the data and used Postman to post data to the API and it works. I just need to create the structure in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have an array of arrays (jagged array) in each property, you can either use `string[][]` or `List<List<string>>` as the type**

```cs
public class Root
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<List<string>> Property1 { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

If the property names are dynamic, you can use a `Dictionary` to contain them

```cs
public class Root
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

And the dictionary keys will be `Property1`, `Property2`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as a dictionary with two nested lists inside.

```
{
//Dictionary
"data": {
    // Dictionary Key with value List<List<string>>
    "Property1": [
      //Entry in List<List<string>>
      [
        //Entry in List<string>
        string,
        string
      ],
      [
        string,
        string
      ]
    ],
   }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

var data = new Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>();
```