# Deserializing undefined list

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have some JSON data that I'm receiving from a third party that I can't figure how to deserialize:

```
{
    "data": {
        "SomeCategory": [
            [
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string"
            ],
            [
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string"
            ]
        ],
        "AnotherRandomCategory": [
            [
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string"
            ],
            [
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string"
            ],
            [
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string"
            ],
            [
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string",
                "some string"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm using the below Model to try and deserialize it, but it doesn't work.

```
public class ContentClass
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public DataClass Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataClass
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public List<CategoryClass> Category { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryClass
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public List<string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Up until the data it deserializes fine. But then I have a dynamically named category that I can't set up in my model, followed by an unnamed list of strings.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: In words: You have an object with property "data". That property is a `Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>`, I would say. Or maybe `Dictionary<string, string[][]>`.

Comment: Assuming that the category names `"SomeCategory"` are not known at compile time, use `public Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> Data` in `ContentClass`.  Will look for a duplicate... Duplicate found: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68563574) by [Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) to [Json serialize C# data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68562942).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var content=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Content>(json);

public class Content
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Dictionary <string, List<List<string>>>  Data { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most JSON libraries (JSON.net, System.Text.Json) expects the JSON to be in camel case. And your property names should match the JSON properties - except your c# variables should be Pascal Case. If they do not, or if it is not appropriate, then you can use the `JsonProperty` attribute to define them.

As an example:

```
public class DataClass
{
    [JsonProperty("SomeCategory")]
    public List<CategoryClass> Category { get; set; }
}
```

Further, as noted in the comments, if the data returned is dynamic, map it to a dictionary. It would look like:

```
public class ContentClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> Data
}
```

No need to set a JsonProperty here as `data` is in the proper format for c# to assign it into the variable `Data` in your class.

Comment: C# doesn't expect anything about case in JSON. It has to do with the library and the selected options.

Comment: @madreflection Using Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json (built into c#) the default is indeed case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, but those are libraries. You said *"C# expects the JSON to be in camel case"* and that is incorrect because that's not C# doing that, it's the library. The same would be true in any language that uses those libraries.

Comment: Apologies, I use c# interchangeably with .net, as one does not usually use c# without it. Will change.

Comment: Please break that habit. The distinction is important and it will mislead new developers. It's important, for new and seasoned developers alike, to understand which component is responsible for a given behavior.

Comment: I understand. I guess since mono is obsolete, the only compiler that uses c# these days is .net, which means you have to use .net to use c#. Why I tend to think that way.

Comment: It wouldn't have mattered which compiler it was, since it's the library, not the language, that applies the behavior.

Comment: Despite the argument concerning the different cases, I'm still grateful for the reply. Thank you @JeffB